# Can Bamboo CI run Xcode Builds?

Tags: xcodebuild, bamboo

Can Bamboo CI run Xcode Builds?  If so,  can someone post a link to an explanation on how to set it up that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out you can run command line builds so I can execute xcodebuilder on bamboo.

Comment: I am about to setup Bamboo CI for an XCode build, any information would be most welcome - We are hosted on JIRA Studio, which I'm guessing will make life harder...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build on a Mac, or any other platform for that matter, you can just install a remote agent:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+remote+agent+installation+guide

If you don't have any remote agents you can use SSH like Paramiko in Python to execute a command:
http://www.lag.net/paramiko/